# Same prediction for each inference

Tags: java, tensorflow

I saved a tensorflow model using `tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder`.
However, when I try to make predictions in java, **in most of the time** it returns the same results (for fc8 (alexnet) the layer before softmax) in some cases, it produces some real different results and it's most likely to be correct, so from that, I assume that the training is OK. 
Did anyone else experienced this? Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

my Java implementation:

```
Tensor image = constructAndExecuteGraphToNormalizeImage(imageBytes);    
Tensor result = s.runner().feed("input_tensor", image).feed("Placeholder_1",t).fetch("fc8/fc8").run().get(0);

private static Tensor constructAndExecuteGraphToNormalizeImage(byte[] imageBytes) {
    try (Graph g = new Graph()) {
        TF.GraphBuilder b = new TF.GraphBuilder(g);
        // Some constants specific to the pre-trained model at:
        // https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/models/inception5h.zip
        //
        // - The model was trained with images scaled to 224x224 pixels.
        // - The colors, represented as R, G, B in 1-byte each were converted to
        //   float using (value - Mean)/Scale.
        final int H = 227;
        final int W = 227;
        final float mean = 117f;
        final float scale = 1f;

        // Since the graph is being constructed once per execution here, we can use a constant for the
        // input image. If the graph were to be re-used for multiple input images, a placeholder would
        // have been more appropriate.
        final Output input = b.constant("input", imageBytes);
        final Output output =
                b.div(
                        b.sub(
                                b.resizeBilinear(
                                        b.expandDims(
                                                b.cast(b.decodeJpeg(input, 3), DataType.FLOAT),
                                                b.constant("make_batch", 0)),
                                        b.constant("size", new int[] {H, W})),
                                b.constant("mean", mean)),
                        b.constant("scale", scale));
        try (Session s = new Session(g)) {
            return s.runner().fetch(output.op().name()).run().get(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that there is no random operation left in your graph, such as dropout. (Seems to be the case, since you often get the same results).

Alas, [some operations in tensorflow seem to be non-deterministic](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3103), such as reductions and convolutions. We have to live with the fact that tensorflow's nets are stochastic beasts: their performance can be approached statistically but their outputs are non-deterministic.

(*I believe some other frameworks such as Theano go farther than tensorflow in proposing deterministic operations.*)