# TensorFlow:Evaluate test set multiple times but get different accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow-serving

I have trained the model of `MNIST` using CNN, but when I check the model's accuracy with test data after the training, I find that my accuracy will improve. Here is the code.

```
BATCH_SIZE = 50
LR = 0.001              # learning rate
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('./mnist', one_hot=True)  # they has been normalized to range (0,1)
test_x = mnist.test.images[:2000]
test_y = mnist.test.labels[:2000]

def new_cnn(imageinput, inputshape):
    weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(inputshape, stddev = 0.1),name = 'weights')
    biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.05, shape = [inputshape[3]]),name = 'biases')
    layer = tf.nn.conv2d(imageinput, weights, strides = [1, 1, 1, 1], padding = 'SAME')
    layer = tf.nn.relu(layer)
    return weights, layer

tf_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 28 * 28])
image = tf.reshape(tf_x, [-1, 28, 28, 1])              # (batch, height, width, channel)
tf_y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, 10])            # input y

# CNN
weights1, layer1 = new_cnn(image, [5, 5, 1, 32])
pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(
    layer1,
    pool_size=2,
    strides=2,
)           # -> (14, 14, 32)
weight2, layer2 = new_cnn(pool1, [5, 5, 32, 64])    # -> (14, 14, 64)
pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(layer2, 2, 2)    # -> (7, 7, 64)
flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])          # -> (7*7*64, )
hide = tf.layers.dense(flat, 1024, name = 'hide')              # hidden layer
output = tf.layers.dense(hide, 10, name = 'output')
loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=tf_y, logits=output)           # compute cost
accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy( labels=tf.argmax(tf_y, axis=1), predictions=tf.argmax(output, axis=1),)[1]
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LR).minimize(loss)



sess = tf.Session()
init_op = tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.local_variables_initializer()) # the local var is for accuracy
sess.run(init_op)     # initialize var in graph
saver = tf.train.Saver()
for step in range(101):
    b_x, b_y = mnist.train.next_batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    _, loss_ = sess.run([train_op, loss], {tf_x: b_x, tf_y: b_y})
    if step % 50 == 0:
        print(loss_)
        accuracy_, loss2 = sess.run([accuracy, loss], {tf_x: test_x, tf_y: test_y })
        print('Step:', step, '| test accuracy: %f' % accuracy_)
```

To simplify the problem, I only use the 100 training iterations. And the final accuracy of test set is approximately `0.655000`.

But when I run the following code:

```
for i in range(5):
  accuracy2 = sess.run(accuracy, {tf_x: test_x, tf_y: test_y })
  print(sess.run(weight2[1,:,0,0])) # To show that the model parameters won't update 
  print(accuracy2)
```

The output is

```
[-0.06928255 -0.13498515  0.01266837  0.05656774  0.09438231]
0.725875
[-0.06928255 -0.13498515  0.01266837  0.05656774  0.09438231]
0.7684
[-0.06928255 -0.13498515  0.01266837  0.05656774  0.09438231]
0.79675
[-0.06928255 -0.13498515  0.01266837  0.05656774  0.09438231]
0.817
[-0.06928255 -0.13498515  0.01266837  0.05656774  0.09438231]
0.832187
```

This makes me confused, can somebody tell me what's wrong? 
Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same prediction for each inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44952929/same-prediction-for-each-inference)

Comment: please include full code. for example wgat do you use keep_prob for?

Comment: @lejlot sorry for that and I delete the redundant part.

Comment: Are you sure the weights do not change? Printing them is not enough, as a single pass may have very small changes, perhaps beyond the printed decimals. Your code exert does not preclude this situation.

Comment: @Eric Platon But the training operation may not  executed during the process of evaluating the test set.

Comment: I see. Sorry, I am not familiar with what `tf.metrics.accuracy` is doing. I assume it just measures, but this remains a guess. Have you looked at the weights in more detail (like printing just a few with full precision) ?

Answer (score 0):

[`tf.metrics.accuracy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/accuracy) is not as trivial as you might think. Take a look at its documentation:

> The `accuracy` function creates two local variables, `total` and
>   `count` that are used to compute the frequency with which
>   `predictions`   matches `labels`. This frequency is ultimately
>   returned as `accuracy`: an   idempotent operation that simply divides
>   `total` by `count`.
>
> Internally, an `is_correct` operation computes a `Tensor` with
>   elements 1.0   where the corresponding elements of `predictions` and
>   `labels` match and 0.0   otherwise. Then `update_op` increments
>   `total` with the reduced sum of the   product of `weights` and
>   `is_correct`, and it increments `count` with the   reduced sum of
>   `weights`.
>
> For estimation of the metric  over a stream of data, the function
>   creates an   `update_op` operation that updates these variables and
>   returns the `accuracy`.
>
> ...
>
> Returns:
>
> - accuracy: A `Tensor` representing the accuracy, the value of `total` divided
>       by `count`.
> - update_op: An operation that increments the `total` and `count` variables
>       appropriately and whose value matches `accuracy`.

Note that it returns a tuple and **you take the second item**, namely `update_op`. Consecutive invocation of `update_op` is treated as streaming of data, which is not what you intend to do (because each evaluation *during training* will affect future evaluations). In fact, this running metric is [pretty counter-intuitive](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9498).

The solution for you is to use plain simple accuracy calculation. Change this line to:

```
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argmax(tf_y, axis=1), tf.argmax(output, axis=1)), tf.float32))
```

and you'll have a stable accuracy calculation.